# Crop simple features object in R

Tags: r, clip, sf

Is there a function to crop sf map object, similar to `maptools::pruneMap(lines, xlim= c(4, 10), ylim= c(10, 15))` used for SpatialPolygon or SpatialLine?

I am considering `st_intersection()` but there can be proper way.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`st_intersection` is probably the best way. Find whatever way works best to get an `sf` object to intersect with your input. Here's a way using the convenience of `raster::extent` and a mix of old and new. `nc` is created by `example(st_read)`:

```
st_intersection(nc, st_set_crs(st_as_sf(as(raster::extent(-82, -80, 35, 36), "SpatialPolygons")), st_crs(nc)))
```

I don't think you can coax `st_intersection` to not need an exact matching CRS, so either set both of them to NA or make sure they are the same. There's no easy tools for bbox/extent afaik, so using raster is good way to make things easy-ish.

Comment: Thanks so much @mdsumner, it worked like a charm. I spent hours on `st_intersection` but couldn't solve it myself.

Comment: You can now use `spex::spex` to replace the `st_as_sf(as(...))` call. Also, `tmaptools::crop_shape()` can do this.

Comment: `sf` now includes `st_crop`, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 35):

[Since today](https://github.com/r-spatial/sf/issues/720), there is a `st_crop` function in the github version of `sf` (`devtools::install_github("r-spatial/sf")`, probably on CRAN in the near future too).

Just issue:

```
st_crop(nc, c(xmin=-82, xmax=-80, ymin=35, ymax=36))
```

The vector **must** be named with `xmin xmax ymin ymax` (in whichever order).

You can also use any object that can be read by `st_bbox` as cropping limits, which is very handy.

Answer (score 5):

Another workaround, for me it was faster for larger shapefiles:

```
library(sf)
library(raster)
library(rgeos)
library(ggplot2)

# Load National Forest shapefile
# https://data.fs.usda.gov/geodata/edw/edw_resources/shp/S_USA.AdministrativeForest.zip
nf.poly <- st_read("S_USA.AdministrativeForest"), "S_USA.AdministrativeForest")

crop_custom <- function(poly.sf) {
  poly.sp <- as(poly.sf, "Spatial")
  poly.sp.crop <- crop(poly.sp, extent(c(-82, -80, 35, 36)))
  st_as_sf(poly.sp.crop)
}

cropped <- crop_custom(nf.poly)
```

Comment: Thanks. It is interesting workflow, combination of raster::crop() and st_as_sf()...+1 from me. I wish we can have this kind of readily accessible function like crop() in future versions of **sf**.  As to the speed, a quick run of system.time with your function reported *user: 5.42, system: 0.09, elapsed 5.52*, while `st_intersection()` approach was *user: 1.18, system: 0.05, elapsed 1.23* on your dataset. (Probably my environment is different with yours... not sure.)

Comment: That's interesting - the st_intersection approach takes around 80s for me.

Comment: Keep in mind that the raster::crop function, when applied to sp geometry objects, acts a wrapper for rgeos functions. Albeit, a very convenient wrapper. The GEOS API operates on WKT objects so, will invariably will be a standard for sf overlay operations.

Comment: And it changes over time, sf now has "spatial indexing" built-in in 0.5-1 https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sf/news.html  so is probably now faster than sp/rgeos.

Comment: `sf` now includes `st_crop`, see my answer for details.

Answer (score 1):

@mdsumner's solution as a function. Works if `rasta` is a RasterBrick, extent, bbox, etc.

```
# Crop a Simple Features Data Frame to the extent of a raster
crop.sf = function(sfdf, rasta) {
  st_intersection(sfdf, st_set_crs(st_as_sf(as(extent(rasta), "SpatialPolygons")), st_crs(sfdf)))
}
```

It throws away the crs information of the raster because I don't know how to convert a raster crs() into an st_crs()

On my machine and for my data sample this has equivalent performance to `raster::crop` with a SpatialLinesDataFrame version of the data.

@pbaylis's solution is about 2.5 times slower:

```
# Slower option.
crop.sf2 = function(sfdf, rasta) {
  st_as_sf(crop(as(sfdf, "Spatial"), rasta))
}
```

Edit: Somebodies comment suggests [spex](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spex/index.html), which produces SpatialPolygons with the crs from the rasta, if it has a crs.

This code uses the same method as spex:

```
# Crop a Simple Features Data Frame to the extent of a raster
crop.sf3 <- function(sfdf, rasta) {
  # Get extent and crs
  ext.sp <- as(extent(rasta), "SpatialPolygons")
  crs(ext.sp) <- crs(rasta)

  # crop
  st_intersection(sfdf, st_as_sf(ext.sp))
}
```

Comment: sf now has an `st_crop` function which is probably worth checking out.